# How much grass can Unity's terrain system handle performantly, and are there any optimizations?

Tags: unity, optimization, art

[Unity 2021.3.0f1]

I'm making an open world game, and I'm creating the open world using the Unity terrain system. My grass model is very simple, the prefab being 4 planes with a grass texture on each side. Once I have placed enough grass though, getting into the few million verts range, the game understandably starts to lag. How can I further optimize the grass, and is there anyway to billboard it at a distance?

Comment: hello,I think you should try [OcclusionCulling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) and [LevelOfDetail](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html)

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. What Unity can handle is dependent on the the target platform & implementation of what it's handling. We have a number of [questions regarding grass in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+grass+is%3Aq) & a few that [specifically mention billboarding](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+grass+billboard+is%3Aq). If those don't address your situation, please edit your question to include the detail of how your project differs & what you've tried so far.